# Manual memory management in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, nested-loops

summary of code: stores over 16 million uint8_t in a 3d array as pointers to those uint8_t.

The code works but why is it that I only saved 4 KB by using uint8_t as opposed to ints. I run this same code with ints it uses 330,488K but with the uint8_t it uses 330,484. I know most of that is the pointers but shouldn't (assuming each int used minimum space) decreasing the size of each 16 million ints from 2bytes to 1 byte have saved more than 4k??? I'm thinking it should have saved closer to 16 MB right?

By "Run the same code with ints" I literally do a "find and replace: uint8_t with int" Then recompile.

```
uint8_t**** num3d;
num3d = new uint8_t***[256];
for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
    num3d[i] = new uint8_t**[256];
    for(int j=0;j<256;j++){
        num3d[i][j] = new uint8_t*[256];
    }
}

// Initialize 
uint8_t *B;
for(int lx = 0;lx<256;lx++){
    for(int ly= 0;ly<256;ly++){
        for(int lz=0;lz<256;lz++){

            if(ly == 0 || lx == 0 || lz == 0 || ly == 255 || lx == 255 || lz == 255){ 
                B = new uint8_t(2);
                num3d[lx][ly][lz] = B;
                continue;
            }
            if(ly < 60){
                B = new uint8_t(1);
                num3d[lx][ly][lz] = B;
                continue;
            }
            B = new uint8_t(0);
            num3d[lx][ly][lz] = B;

        } // inner inner loop

    } // inner loop

} // outer loop
```

Comment: I just saw this and get amazed by this `uint8_t**** num3d;` o_o

Comment: _'... I know they must have included memory management into normal ints that isn't included with uint8_t. ...'_ Most of your 2 questions is written in a way, I simply can't deduce what your real problems are (I'm pretty sure these are others as you're asking for).

Comment: Two words: Encapsulation and abstraction. *That's* what you have to learn. Then memory manages itself.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you for the advice. I will try to learn everything I can about those two concepts.

Comment: @DanielSanchez Lol! A pointer to an array that points to arrays that themselves point to more arrays that then point to the data.

Comment: @KlaytonCurran Yeah!! I know about it, it's just that is the first time I've seen this in use...xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" My question is what is it about int that allows it to work using full 32 bit ints and how would I replicate what the program already does with ints for use with 8 bit ints. I know they must have included memory management into normal ints that isn't included with uint8_t."

Well, `int` is *at least* 16 bits, 32 bits isn't even guaranteed. But ignoring that, the fact is that each integral type has a certain range. `std::numeric_limits<int>` or `<uint_8>` will tell you the respective ranges. Obviously you can't use an 8 bit number to count from 0 to 256. You can only count to 255.

Also, there's no memory management at all for `int` and other simple types like `uint_8`. The compiler justs says "The integer with name Foo is stored in these bytes" and that's it. No management needed. There are a few minor variations, e.g. an `int` member of a struct is stored "in these bytes of the struct" etcetera.

Comment: Hmm Okay then is there a memory hole I'm missing after fixing the loops?

Comment: Sorry had to quick edit a stupid comment that I made before my 5 min was up so I chose the above to say. Now for some reason I have a memory hole when running this code with ints for the loops and  pointers to uint8_t as the array type but when I run the exact code worded the exact same (I do a "find and replace" on the whole block and change uint8_t to int) boom: no memory hole.

Comment: Theres no memory hole now using both int8_t and int but why does using int8_t only save 4KB over int when I'm storing 16 million of them? Assuming each int stored only used 2bytes shouldn't it have saved closer to 16 MB?

Comment: @KlaytonCurran: It's probably coincidence that you saved anything at all. Allocations have some overhead and are typically rounded up; 8 or 16 bytes would be common. Allocating uint_8 with `new` may therefore have 16x overhead.

Comment: I filled the integer version using 'new' as well. So would that mean uint8_t has more overhead than a normal int?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to question 1)... This loops goes for ever:

```
for (uint8_t i=0;i<256;i++)
```

Indeed the range of number which can be representable by a `uint8_t` is `0...255`. So don't use `uint8_t` here !

It seems to me that since your computer is allocating is this loop, it will end up eating all memory therefore question 2) doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It also causes a massive memory leak (since each iteration is allocating memory ... which never gets deleted, but the pointer to it does get changed to a new allocation in the next iteration).  Which is what causes him to run out of memory (which, I believe, answers #2).

Comment: Ahh thanks! I also figured out the best way to do it would be to define the variable before the loop then delete it after instead of having the loop create it. question 1 solved.